# Login with facebook on fullstack generator

Tags: facebook, oauth, yeoman

I have generated a fullstack server with Yeoman's *generator-angular-fullstack* to function as a backend to my iOS app, and now I would like to use the Facebook OAuth implementation, but I can't seem to find what I need to pass to my server and what I need to set on Facebook's end.

When I add my client ID and secret to config/local.env.sample.js and perform a GET request to /auth/facebook; I get this error:

```
Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.
```

I do not know where I need to set this URL, can't seem to find it on Facebook itself, and I don't really know where to look on my server.

Also, if someone can find an example implementation of Facebook OAuth with this fullstack generator, please post it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try renaming `config/local.env.sample.js` to `config/local.env.js` then check the file `server/auth/facebook/`

The cookie is set by the function `setTokenCookie()` in `server/auth/auth.service.js`